# @Conditional matches method is invoked n+1 times

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Why boolean **matches(...)** method in SpecificCaseCondition class is invoked 2 times ? I expect it to be invoked only once, on AnyConfiguration creation. In fact, it's invoked 2 times.

```java
public class SpecificCaseCondition implements Condition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        return true;
    }
}


@Configuration
@Conditional(SpecificCaseCondition.class)
public class AnyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Service firstService() {
        return new RealService();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Service secondService() {
        return new RealService();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Service thirdService() {
        return new RealService();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could show the code of SpecificCaseCondition class?

Comment: SpecificCaseCondition implements Condition(org.springframework.context.annotation) and matches method always returns "true".  and yep, all 3 beans will be loaded if condition is true, otherwise, nothing will be loaded and AnyConfiguration won't be created

Comment: You should edit the question to include extra content instead of using a comment. I've done so for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Spring Boot auto-configures the beans for the app context, it does so in multiple *phases*. By default, condition at the class level* will be evaluated multiple times, for each phase. That's probably why you're seeing your custom `Condition` method being called more than once; Spring is invoking it during each phase.

One way to avoid that would be to annotate the `@Bean` *methods* with `@Conditional` instead of the entire *class*. Like this:

```java
@Configuration
public class AnyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Conditional(SpecificCaseCondition.class)
    public Service firstService() {
        return new RealService();
    }
    
    @Bean
    @Conditional(SpecificCaseCondition.class)
    public Service secondService() {
        return new RealService();
    }
    
    @Bean
    @Conditional(SpecificCaseCondition.class)
    public Service thirdService() {
        return new RealService();
    }
}
```

In my experiments, method-level conditions are only evaluated during the `REGISTER_BEAN` phase.

There is a downside to this solution, of course - it isn't very [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). As an alternative, you can change your condition to implement `ConfigurationCondition` which has a method, `public ConfigurationPhase getConfigurationPhase()`, to dictate which phase the condition should be evaluated in.

---

- The various `@Conditional*` annotations can be placed at the class level or the method level.